# How to select with regex in Java text between curly brace

Tags: java, jquery, regex

Let's assume that I have a text : `{ t e x t }` . I need to select it with regex (it can be a random value between `{ }`. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried?  What didn't work?  This isn't a regex writing service.

Comment: https://regexr.com check out the cheatsheet in the panel on the left. If you have code you've tried, please edit the question to include it so we can help you debug the problem

Comment: If the string starts and ends with `{}`, you don't need regex, you just need `String.substring`.

Comment: Java has no connection to jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/UvR8SB/1), `\{([^\}]*)\}` and capture group#1.

**Explantaion of the regex**:

- `\{`: The character, `{`
- `(`: Start of capturing group#1

  - `[^\}]*`: Any character other than `}`, any number of times
- `)`: End of capturing group#1
- `\}`: The character, `}`

**Java Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "{ t e x t }";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{([^\\}]*)\\}").matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 t e x t
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PHU0YC)